# how to access local procedures in tpool initcmd

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I have series of local procedure are written in local file and also i am using same file for tpool creation, I was trying to access few local procedures in tpool body it didn't get results from local procedures,

However I could able execute init body but the local procedure not able call from tpool, is there any mechanism to access local procedures

```
package require Thread
package require tdom

proc proc1 {response xpath} {
    set doc ""
    set root ""
    set node ""
    .....
}

proc proc2 {response xpath} {
    set doc ""
    set root ""
    set node ""
   .....
}

proc proc3 {one two} {
    set res1 proc1 $one
    set res2 proc2 $two
    .....
}
set startMyProc {
    proc download {one two three four} {
        set res [proc3 $one $two $three $four]
    }
}

proc Threaded {one two three four} {
    variable startMyProc
    set pool [tpool::create -maxworkers 10 -initcmd $startMyProc]

    # Sent the work into the pool as distinct jobs
    set jobs [list]
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $one]} {incr i} {
        lappend  jobs [tpool::post -nowait $pool [list download [lindex $one $] $two $three $four]]
    }
    while {[llength $jobs] > 0} {
        tpool::wait $pool $jobs jobs
    }
    tpool::release $pool
}

Threaded xxx xxx xxx xxxx
```

Thanks
Malli

Answer (score 0):

A few minor issues.  The variable startMyProc should contain all code for the thread. The one you have now has procs outside of the variable that are unreachable.  Also you should put a catch inside the initial proc to help you find errors in the thread like this.

```
set startMyProc {
        proc proc1 {response xpath} {
                set doc ""
                set root ""
                set node ""
        }

        proc proc2 {response xpath} {
                set doc ""
                set root ""
                set node ""
        }

        proc proc3 {one two} {
                puts "proc3"
                set res1 proc1 $one
                set res2 proc2 $two
        }

        proc download {one two three four} {
                if {[catch {
                        set res [proc3 $one $two $three $four]
                } err]} {
                        puts $err
                }
        }
}
```

For some reason the threads are still running or cleaning up when the main thread closes.  Add this to the bottom of your main script to keep it opened until ctrl-c.  You'll have to figure out how to gently close while the threads are finishing but this will get you by for now.

```
vwait forever
```